# Converting timezone from UTC using numbers as opposed to names for timezones in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, timezone, google-bigquery

I know that in BigQuery one can convert a timestamp by DATETIME(timestamp, timezone). But the names of the timezones in SQL are very poorly organized. I was wondering if there is a function or a way to convert from a time in 
UTC to some other timezone using a string of number like "+00:04" or "4" where the number would indicate the amount of hours the timezone is ahead or behind the UTC time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a timezone by supplying its UTC offset using the following format:

```
(+|-)H[H][:M[M]]
```

For example:

```
-07:00

SELECT CURRENT_DATETIME('-07:00'), DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '-07:00')
```

Comment: Why don't you try it? For example, `SELECT TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATETIME(), '-8');`